# Which Unity project files can be ignored for version control?

Tags: version-control, unity-game-engine

Which files / directories in a unity project can be safely ignored when checking into version control (SVN / GIT)?

Temp/

/Library/cache/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First set Edit -> Project Settings -> Asset Serialization = force text

Then use this file for git: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore (copy in the main folder near Assets, Library etc.). If using svn stop using svn.

And yes, the .meta files are necessary.

Comment: noting however that one should simply use svn for Unity

Answer (score 0):

[gitgnore.io](http://gitignore.io) is a great resource for this. Select Unity, your IDE, and your OS.