# Missing reference in inspector after updating from git - Unity

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

The first programmer creates a public variable (GameObject, for example) in any script, then he assigns a game object to this variable in the inspector, then he makes a push, then the second programmer gets an update and there is no game object in the inspector. We have .meta files in our project, Asset Serialization mode is Force Text, also we use git and bitbucket. It happens not all the time and not with all references, only sometimes. What's the problem and how can we fix it? Unity 5.3.3, but it also happened with prev versions.

Comment: Do you see any diffs in your commit when saving the scene?

Comment: you don't use git for filmmaking, gamemaking and the like. git is for *source* control, when you have a few text files because you're writing Linux.  generall you simply use svn for things like games.  in any even if for some reason you must use git, https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Unity project files can be ignored for version control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127601/which-unity-project-files-can-be-ignored-for-version-control)

Answer (score 5):

This is an old Unity glitch, when scene loads partially or in broken state or does not react to file system changes.
Try to open the scene one more time with File -> Open Scene

Comment: 2021 still existing this bug